# Apache random IPs in access log trying to execute scripts

Tags: apache

I just got a quick question. My apache access log has random IPs from China, Japan, etc. It looks like they are trying to execute scripts from where they are.

The log looks like this: `171.117.10.221 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:05:04 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.dongtaiwang.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.3$
1.202.79.71 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:05:06 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.epochtimes.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K$
113.128.104.239 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:05:11 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.wujieliulan.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Ge$
117.14.157.148 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:05:17 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.ntdtv.com/ HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/$
110.177.75.106 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:05:37 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.dongtaiwang.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/$
221.11.229.244 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:05:57 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.epochtimes.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) Appl$
182.101.57.39 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:06:03 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.epochtimes.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) Apple$
113.128.104.88 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:06:13 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.epochtimes.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) Appl$
106.114.65.1 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:06:14 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.wujieliulan.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45$
113.128.104.148 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:06:31 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.ntdtv.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46$
114.221.124.84 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:06:45 -0800] "GET /ogPipe.aspx?name=http://www.ntdtv.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3847 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 $
172.104.108.109 - - [29/Jan/2018:08:17:50 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 830 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"` (None of these are my IPs, that's why I am putting them out there.)

I used an IP lookup site to see where they are. Does anyone have any advice towards what I should do?

Comment: Surprisingly, I got here after seeing this log on my AWS lambda `req from xxx/ogPipe.aspx?name=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ntdtv.com%2F` about 25mn after I posted the actual website URL on Github. Web scrawlers are everywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a new tls prober from GFW.

The https://example.com/ogPipe.aspx is a tool to bridge some blocked news website in china.(you can see the target websites in log lines)

GFW indeeds to detect/figure out it.

Here's my splunk search result of these 3 days.

[remote_ip.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbaqH.png)

[user_agent.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgCQk.png)

The features of the prober.

1. Source ip is a one-shot address
2. User-Agent is simulated to Chrome/Safari/Firefox
3. TLS Protocol is TLSv1.2

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Ignore them.

Long answer: There are plenty of vulnerabilities in various web servers / application frameworks that hackers want to abuse. Those originating IPs may not be the hackers themselves but victims of some malware / trojan horses remotely controlled by hackers. Those victims were used by hackers to dig if your server is vulnerable for a more promising rewards, e.g. access to your database or passwords. If you are hosting a .net framework application, look closely for any announcement of vulnerability and apply security patches if available. Especially if you have a "ogPipe.aspx" file serving, you should examine every line of code in it to see whether there is security loophole. As shown in your server log, it responded http code 404 meaning that you don't serve ogPipe.aspx, so you are safe. As a prevailing security advice, look closely for any announcement of vulnerability (from your software vendor, e.g. Apache / Microsoft) and apply security patches if available.